# Why http is taking some time to load in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

I am trying to update the array value but inside httpClient method it is working But it is not working outside. So, how to resolve this issue in angular 14.

app.component.ts:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.httpClient.get<string[]>('../assets/data.json').subscribe((data) => {
      this.groupData = data;
      console.log(this.groupData); // it should be data.json value
  }); 
   
  }
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-1hqg9x?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: You are trying to log sync a value from an async call.

Comment: You don't need httpClient to get data from an asset

Comment: not, you get the value **inside** subscribe function an httpClient.get is async, that main that Angular only call to execute the action, then continue running your code it's the reason you get an empty value outside subscribe function

Comment: @Eliseo :Can you edit my stackblitz?

Comment: @EMahanK, [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbdrtu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) NOTE: you should use a service instead of use the httpClient in the component. The reason is to have "separate" the component of the call to the API. In a future you could change the file or you get the data from a dbs. It's more comfortable change the service that the component (and avoid errors)

Answer (score 3):

The observable is resolved asynchronously and thus your log-message is written before the http call returns

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
      this.httpClient.get<string[]>('../assets/data.json').subscribe((data) => {
      this.groupData = data;
      console.log(this.groupData); // now you see the resolved data
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Not Working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ctyjxa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-nxdkqd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: @EMahanK and TmTron: should be **this.httpClient.get<string[]>('assets/data.json')**. See that "assets has no `../`. When you build an Angular app (`ng build`) by defect create the index.html, the bundles files (the javascript and the .css) in a folder `dist`. Angular copy also the assets folder in `dist/assets`, (you can change in angular.json).The index.html (also by defect) has a `<base href="/">` so all are reffered to the "dist" folder. So you use `/assets` or `assets` but **not** ../assets. see [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hbdrtu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: This happens also when you use a `<img src="assets/img/myImage.jpg"/>`.